# SSL vulnerability in Tivoli Monitoring Agent

Tags: windows, ssl, tivoli

I am fixing some deviations on a windows server 2008, and in the scan results the vulnerability SSL Enabled Server Supports Medium Strength SSL Encryption Certificates/Ciphers appeared in port 7756. The application that is running in that port is kntcma(Tivoli Monitoring agent). I tried to fix this by going to TEMS->Advanced->Edit variables and add the next lines:

```
GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV2=OFF
GSK_PROTOCOL_SSLV3=ON
GSK_V3_CIPHER_SPECS="350A"
```

Then I restarted the agent and thought that would be enough to solve the vulnerability, but it didn't. The deviation continues to appear and I don't know what else to do to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can use certificates... here are some steps to recreate the security certificates:

#### a) Set properties:

`C:\IBM\ITM\InstallITM\GetGSKitHome.bat`  **-> add the output at the beginning of the PATH**

example:

`set PATH=C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7\lib;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7\bin;%PATH%`

`C:\IBM\ITM\InstallITM\GetJavaHome.bat` **-> set the output of this command as the JAVA_HOME**

example:

`set JAVA_HOME=C:\IBM\ITM\java\java50\jre`

#### b) Delete and recreate certificates

**on 32 bits servers where only gsk7capicmd utility is available:**

`set PATH=C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7\lib;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7\bin;%PATH%`

`gsk7capicmd.exe -cert -delete -db C:\IBM\ITM\keyfiles\keyfile.kdb -pw IBM61TIV -label "IBM_Tivoli_Monitoring_Certificate"`

**on 32 bits servers where gsk8capicmd utility is available:**

`set PATH=C:\IBM\ITM\GSK8;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK8\lib;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK8\bin;%PATH%`

`gsk8capicmd.exe -cert -delete -db C:\IBM\ITM\keyfiles\keyfile.kdb -pw IBM61TIV -label "IBM_Tivoli_Monitoring_Certificate"`

**on 64 bits servers where only gsk7capicmd_64 is available:**

`set PATH=C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7_x64;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7_x64\lib64;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7_x64\bin;%PATH%`

`gsk7capicmd_64.exe -cert -delete -db C:\IBM\ITM\keyfiles\keyfile.kdb -pw IBM61TIV -label "IBM_Tivoli_Monitoring_Certificate"`

**on 64 bits servers where gsk8capicmd_64 is available:**

`set PATH=C:\IBM\ITM\GSK8_x64;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK8_x64\lib64;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK8_x64\bin;%PATH%`

`gsk8capicmd_64.exe -cert -delete -db C:\IBM\ITM\keyfiles\keyfile.kdb -pw IBM61TIV -label "IBM_Tivoli_Monitoring_Certificate"`

#### c) create new certificate

**on 32 bits servers where only gsk7capicmd utility is available:**

`set PATH=C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7\lib;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7\bin;%PATH%`

`gsk7capicmd.exe -cert -create -db C:\IBM\ITM\keyfiles\keyfile.kdb -pw IBM61TIV -size 4096 -dn "CN=IBM Tivoli Monitoring Self-Signed Certificate,O=IBM Tivoli,C=US" -label "IBM_Tivoli_Monitoring_Certificate" -default_cert yes -expire 3652 -sigalg sha1`

**on 32 bits servers where gsk8capicmd utility is available:**

`set PATH=C:\IBM\ITM\GSK8;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK8\lib;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK8\bin;%PATH%`

`gsk8capicmd.exe -cert -create -db C:\IBM\ITM\keyfiles\keyfile.kdb -pw IBM61TIV -size 4096 -dn "CN=IBM Tivoli Monitoring Self-Signed Certificate,O=IBM Tivoli,C=US" -label "IBM_Tivoli_Monitoring_Certificate" -default_cert yes -expire 3652 -sigalg sha1`

**on 64 bits servers where gsk7capicmd_64 utility is available:**

`set PATH=C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7_x64;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7_x64\lib64;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK7_x64\bin;%PATH%`

`gsk7capicmd_64.exe -cert -create -db C:\IBM\ITM\keyfiles\keyfile.kdb -pw IBM61TIV -size 4096 -dn "CN=IBM Tivoli Monitoring Self-Signed Certificate,O=IBM Tivoli,C=US" -label "IBM_Tivoli_Monitoring_Certificate" -default_cert yes -expire 3652 -sigalg sha1`

**on 64 bits servers where gsk8capicmd_64 utility is available:**

`set PATH=C:\IBM\ITM\GSK8_x64;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK8_x64\lib64;C:\IBM\ITM\GSK8_x64\bin;%PATH%`

`gsk8capicmd_64.exe -cert -create -db C:\IBM\ITM\keyfiles\keyfile.kdb -pw IBM61TIV -size 4096 -dn "CN=IBM Tivoli Monitoring Self-Signed Certificate,O=IBM Tivoli,C=US" -label "IBM_Tivoli_Monitoring_Certificate" -default_cert yes -expire 3652 -sigalg sha1`

You can find more information at this [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Tivoli%20Monitoring/page/ITM%20Certificate%20Authentication%20Configuration%20Guide%20for%20ITM%206.2.2%20and%20newer%20releases).

Comment: Forgot to mention it would be nice to patch SSLv3 for protect from POODLE vulnerability, as described at the [following link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21691775)